# align right and left concepts changes when run app in farsi Android phones

Tags: android, css, layout, alignment, right-to-left

I'm developing Farsi apps on my English language android phone and all stuffs about Right-to-left is handled well. but recently I find out that when I run my app on farsi language android os's, all right and left concepts changes! all layout that I aligned Right, then go Left and also Left aligend layout and also `alignParentStart`. so how I can develop my app so I all be Right to left in all kind of phones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem is resolved by adding this line to application:

```
android:supportsRtl="true"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `resConfig "en"` in `defaultConfig` of build.gradle